# VideoView cannot find the video Android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I have a simple app which has to play a hardcoded video using VideoView.

This is my code in MainActivity.java

```
simpleVid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.simpleVid);  
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Pictures/Default_user.avi"; 
simpleVid.setVideoPath(path);
simpleVid.start();
```

But it says 'Sorry, cannot play the video' and when I checked the run console, it says

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Default_user.avi (Permission denied)

Though I have given READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest file and the video is there in Internal Storage/Pictures. What might be the reason for this?

Comment: You have to add Runtime permissions for Read external storage.

Comment: For this if you have version greater than 23 you have to give runtime permission otherwise you have to specific permission in manifest...

Comment: Beware that accepted answer is incorrect. You don't need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, and you don;t need to enable anything in app settings. Only thing you need is to request runtime permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Make sure in App settings permission will provided by user

Comment: Oh shoot, I hadn't given user permission. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not required for this, as well as giving something in app settings. The runtime permissions to `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is only thing that is required here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Add these permissions to your Manifest first.

After that you need to request these permissions at runtime. There are many tutorials out there which can teach you how to do that properly.

Read more about permissions here:

[Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview)